# DOM events in webkitgtk /python

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygobject

I am trying to use webkit_dom_event_target_add_event_listener function in python. After lot of research, I am reaching to the conclusion that this function is available only in C. My current interest in events is mostly trapping the clicks on elements and acting on it.

Can I use something else to get notification of events on python side of the world? One hacky way I can think is to have event handlers in javascript and then use alert handler to pass the data to python. Is there any other way, I can get notifications of events in python?

For the purpose of discussion, the page webkit is displaying is completely within my control and its code can be adjusted easily.

Tried this on ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is still [broken for Python](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77835) and all other language bindings, except C :(

Comment: Thanks for the bug link. However I had already seen that one and hence concluded that I can not use it. What I am looking for is another way out if possible - like I can parse the string from alert message etc. I am wondering if some other techniques do exist to get me around the problem.

Comment: You could try wrapping the C api with cffi.